# Perl code is exiting without an error using IO::SELECT and IO::Socket::UNIX but doesn't exit using NETCAT (nc) why?

Tags: perl, sockets, unix

It looks like (to me) PERL is crashing without an ERROR but it also looks like (to me) that I must be doing something wrong. What everything looks like is very strange as PERL *exits* mid-code without an ERROR and it should not... unless I am wrong... which probably I am... which is why I am asking for HELP!

I've confirmed the code below exhibits the same behavior with a virgin CENTOS 8 (I used Rocky) system and it *EXITS*... please can someone help me and explain why as really I don't know what things are going on so I am aksing for help!

Two simple PERL programs:

```
   ./listen_socket.pl
   ./send_socket.pl sending_this
```

Send socket is effectively a simple netcat... nc.

NETCAT works.... if I use:

```
  echo send_this | nc -U /tmp/whydontyouwork.sock
```

then "listen_socket.pl" does not exit and behaves as expected.
If I execute this:

```
./send_socket.pl send_this
```

then it fails.

**I don't understand why.
Please help me and tell me where I am an idiot cos I dunno!**

Here are the two perl programs:  (listen_socket.pl)     and   (send_socket.pl)

**listen_socket.pl:**

```
use warnings;
use IO::Select;
use IO::Socket::UNIX;

my $SOCK_PATH   = "/tmp/whydontyouwork.sock";
my $socket;
my $sel         = IO::Select->new();

unlink $SOCK_PATH;
setup();
main();

print STDERR "I know I never get here...see below..\n";


sub setup {
  $socket = new IO::Socket::UNIX(
      Type   => SOCK_STREAM,
      Local  => $SOCK_PATH,
      Listen => 5,
  );
  $sel->add($socket);
}

sub main {
  while ( 1 == 1 ) {
    while(my @ready = $sel->can_read(1)) {
      foreach my $fh (@ready) {
        if($fh == $socket) {
          # Create a new socket
          my $new = $socket->accept;
          $sel->add($new);
        }
        else {
          # Process socket
          if ( 1 == 1 ) {
            my $data = <$fh>;
            if ( defined $data ) {
              print STDERR "I am here...I GET HERE!!";
              print $fh "\n";
              print STDERR "..and all done and I NEVER GET HERE!!??.\n";
              $sel->remove($fh);
              $fh->close;
            }
          }
          print STDERR "Howdie here?   Nope..\n";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**send_socket.pl:**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Socket;

my $SOCK_PATH = "/tmp/whydontyouwork.sock";

if ( $ARGV[0] ) {
    socket(CLIENT, PF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    connect(CLIENT, sockaddr_un($SOCK_PATH));
    print CLIENT $ARGV[0] ;
    close CLIENT;
    exit;
}
exit 1;
```

WORKS ==>
 `echo send_this | nc -U /tmp/whydontyouwork.sock`
NOT WORKS ==>
 `perl ./send_socket.pl send_this`

Comment: *"then it fails."* and *"NOT WORKS"* are not useful error description. Please do proper error handling in Perl to get the details of why, where and how it fails instead of simply ignoring all errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have added the output of each run, at least tell us the listener dies with `Broken pipe` which would have made it more obvious what your issue is.

In any case, it looks like your sender is closing the socket and then the listener is trying to write to it.

You can technically ignore the broken pipe and have your output be the same for the perl example by adding `$SIG{PIPE} = 'IGNORE';` to the listener, but that of course does not fix the (lack of) logic.

But, really, you should read up a bit more about programming with sockets, as what you were trying to do did not make much sense, and, even more importantly, you should actually pay attention to the error messages for hints to what is going on.

Comment: Thank you... my issue was that PERL did not give me a broken PIPE warning. And I did put a TRY / CATCH around it in my testing using Syntax::Keyword::Try however that did not catch the error either.

Comment: Adding the $SIG{PIPE} = 'IGNORE'; did fix the issue.

Comment: The broken pipe would be in the listener's STDERR. So where you see it depends on how you are running the listener. If you started it with something like `perl listen_socket.pl` on a terminal, it would appear on that terminal. But you can accept the answer if that's what you needed...

Comment: I will make some more tests and report back... I do thank you for your advice and will report back in an hour.  It did not appear on the shell either. It just bombed out with no error, no nothing which left me very confused.... I have something to grapple with now so thank you.

Comment: So the issue was printing to a broken PIPE and for whatever reason no errors were reported on the client or server end and the code exited. "nc" worked because as it allows the server to send back a response before the connection was closed.  I would have expected a "broken pipe" error message somewhere.  Thank you for your help... this is the great thing about Stack.